# Show that the polynomial function $f(m,n)=1/2((m+n)^2+3n+m)$ is one to one and onto

Tags: analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory, polynomials

I'm trying to prove that $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ is equinumerous to $\mathbb{N}$ using that fact the function $f:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ defined by $f(m,n)=1/2((m+n)^2+3n+m)$ is a bijection. Pick two different points $(m,n)$ and $(m',n')$ from $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$. I have have tried to break into cases depending on whether $m=m'$, $m\lt m'$, or $m\gt m'$. But I can't finish the whole process. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f(m%2Cn)%3D1%2F2((m%2Bn)%5E2%2B3n%2Bm)%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Abijection&p=1), I had just found the proposed duplicate question. There are also quite a few other basically duplicate questions here, e.g., [Prove a bijection between $\mathbb{N}^2$ and $\mathbb{N}$.](/q/3855108), [How to prove that $(a,b)\mapsto \frac{1}{2}((a+b)^{2}+3a+b)$ is bijective?](/q/2473651), [How would you reverse this double-variable equation?](/q/447989), ...

Comment: (cont.) [How does one get the formula for this bijection from $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ onto $\mathbb{N}$?](/q/29420), [Countability of cartesian product of $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$](/q/132831), [Diophantine equation to characterize natural numbers](/q/297594), etc.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thank you very much. I've found the answer

Comment: @Sil Thank you very much. I've found the answer